# optimizing the java code for better memory

Tags: java, algorithm, jakarta-ee

I need to write a function which will do the following functionalities

Answer (score 1):

Note that this:

```
fqField.substring(quoteEnd+1, fqField.length());
```

uses the character array of the referenced string, rather than create a new string. That is, if I have a 100,000 character array and I take a 2 character substring of that, the substring will reference the original 100,000 chars. This is true even if you dispose of the reference to the original string.

If you do this:

```
new String(fqField.substring(quoteEnd+1, fqField.length()));
```

then this will create a new String, with a new underlying character array. You can then dispose of the original and you won't be consuming memory for the original.

Comment: @assylias, care to add a link for that?

Comment: @Michael-O [this post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html) explains what happened. The String class has been significantly redesigned. You can have a look at the source for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList "prefixes" which you're creating has the default size for a list. You could add a sensible size to it.

What about using char instead of String, is it an option for you to pass that as params?

How about making "prefixes" an array of String (or char) from the start, instead of making it an ArrayList first and converting it later.